# Install BIOS in motherboard from USB for first boot

Tags: boot, usb, motherboard, bios

I have just bought a new motherboard the [MSI H81M-E33](http://www.msi.com/product/mb/H81M-E33.html). The thing is that I have to install the BIOS through a CD, which is in the package.

My old DVD-R's are IDE and the new momtherboard doesn't support IDE devices.

Is there a way to install BIOS from a USB stick?

It's kind of urgent to use the desktop(it's my girlfriend's) and it will take two weeks to have IDE to sata adapters...

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by updating the BIOS.  The general rule with a BIOS update unless there is a specific reason to update it, don't update it, because it already works

Comment: @Ramhound: Thank you very much for your comment.I don't want to upgrade BIOS. I've just bought a new motherboard and I suppose I have to install BIOS(at least that's what the quick installation guide says) through a CD. The problem is that the old drives are IDE and the new motherboard doesn't support IDE devices.

Comment: Your motherboard already has BIOS instaled.  Unless your CPU requires a higher revision there is no reason to upgrade your BIOS.  You can indeed upgrade your BIOS with a USB device but you can also update it through Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that you are talking about a BIOS and not UEFI? Because if you are I need to start with a warning:

Upgrading the BIOS is **somewhat risky**. If the upgrade fails (e.g, due to a power failure mid re-flash) you end up with a bricked system. There are exceptions to this, e.g. expensive systems with two BIOS chips, or with a minimal backup BIOS which allows you to try to write the BIOS again, but those are not common.

Therefor the only regular reason to do do a BIOS upgrade usually is:

1. The newer BIOS version has a new feature which you need.
2. You want all systems to have the same BIOS version (which is not uncommon in large firms with hundred of identical systems, but which you will rarely encounter at home).

---

OK, having said that: Upgrading should be done with care. Risky stuff like IDE to SATA convertors should be avoided.

Which leaves you a few options:

1. Do not upgrade the BIOS. Use the current one.
2. Or get/borrow a SATA CD/DVDROM.
3. Or risk it and hope that the adapter does things properly.

Personally I would use the already installed BIOS and just use it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Perhaps there is something I don't get here. The new and unused motherboard has already BIOS installed? What I mean is, I bought a new CPU, new mobo and new RAM. I just plug  CPU, RAM and the Graphics Card on the new motherboard, press the power on button and everything works fine?

Comment: Let me get that straight. The new hardware is the CPU, the RAM and the motherboard. The old hardware is the graphics card, the HDD(which runs windows xp) and the optical drives. in order to make the PC work again, I just plug the new and the old hardware on the new motherboard and everything is going to work as before? BIOS is installed on the HDD? I think it runs as a firmware...

Comment: So I should try it and what I understand is if any problems occur, these will have to do with the OS rather than the hardware. If there is a problem with xp, I believe I can always boot with a live linux USB, back up all the files and reinstall the OS, isn't that right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10662/discussion-between-thanos-and-hennes)